# making a folder visible in eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to load tomcat 7 into eclipse using  [this tutorial](http://eclipse.dzone.com/tips/launching-and-debugging-tomcat).

When I unzipped to the folder associated with the project, the tomcat folder was loaded as a subfolder.  I therefore dragged all the folders into the root folder of the new tomcat7 eclipse project.  The only folder which eclipse would not move is the bin folder.  Eclipse instead gives me a dialog box with the following error message:  "The element 'bin' exists in the selected destination.  You can either skip the conflicting element, skip all conflicting elements, or cancel the whole operation."

The problem is that there is no bin folder present.  Eclipse does not show a bin folder in the tomcat7 project within eclipse.  And the windows explorer view of the file system also does not show any folder named bin within the tomcat7 folder in the directory hierarchy associated with the workspace.

I feel that I need the contents of the bin folder in the place where eclipse can see and work with them.  Can anyone show me how to move the contents of the bin folder into the place where eclipse will see them?  Now, the bin folder is stuck as a subfolder within the tomcat subfolder within the tomcat7 project.

Answer (score 0):

As your default Java Output Folder for the project, it's hidden in the Package Explorer since everything that goes there was either compiled from or copied from a visible Source Folder.  Use the Navigator View when working at this low a level instead.